Update end date of current record with today's date and and update start_date of new record with today's date
Current record:

When I update the value of current record's activity_weightage as 2 it should pick up start_date as current_date and end_date as 31/12/2099.

and it should update the original record's end date with today's date.

How to write SQL with the same?
UPDATE activity_demo
SET 
    end_date = CURRENT_DATE
WHERE 
    activity_type = 'Digital - Content Syndication'
    AND end_date = '31/12/2099';
INSERT INTO activity_demo (activity_type, activity_weightage, start_date, end_date)
VALUES 
    ('Digital - Content Syndication', 
    2,  -- New activity_weightage
    CURRENT_DATE,  -- Start date is today's date
    '31/12/2099');  -- End date remains '31/12/2099'

I am not able to get it correct by above query.

First, you need to describe the behavior you're seeing, and how it deviates from the expectation or any error messages. Second, we need to know the precise data types defined for the start and end date columns. Finally, MySQL expects ISO8601 date literals, ie 2099-12-13 instead of 31/12/2099.

@JoelCoehoorn u can use any date format i just need to update the dates and i want to see the logic and try to correct mine with your help.

The insert cannot know that it should acquire the end date from activity_weightage = 1 and your update does not check for activity weightage =1 You might consider doing this in a procedure where you have more control

@alex You only use other formats if you don't care about MySQL interpreting the values wrong on certain edge cases.

You are using a non standard date format but if you wish to continue doing so use date_format function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format
select cURRENT_DATE,date_format(CURRENT_DATE,'%m/%d/%Y')

+--------------+--------------------------------------+
| cURRENT_DATE | date_format(CURRENT_DATE,'%m/%d/%Y') |
+--------------+--------------------------------------+
| 2024-10-11   | 10/11/2024                           |
+--------------+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)


noted sir will do the same

A model:
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name INT, 
  age INT DEFAULT 1,
  start_date DATE DEFAULT (DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)),
  end_date DATE DEFAULT '2099-12-31'
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES
(DEFAULT, 111, DEFAULT, '1999-01-01', DEFAULT),
(DEFAULT, 222, DEFAULT, '1999-01-01', DEFAULT);
SELECT * FROM test;




id
name
age
start_date
end_date




1
111
1
1999-01-01
2099-12-31


2
222
1
1999-01-01
2099-12-31



INSERT INTO test
SELECT CASE WHEN temp.id = 0 THEN src.id END, 
       src.name, 
       src.age + temp.id,
       CURRENT_DATE,
       src.end_date
FROM test src
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1) temp (id)
WHERE src.name = 111 AND src.end_date = '2099-12-31'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
test.start_date = src.start_date,
test.end_date = CURRENT_DATE

SELECT * FROM test;




id
name
age
start_date
end_date




1
111
1
1999-01-01
2024-10-11


2
222
1
1999-01-01
2099-12-31


3
111
2
2024-10-11
2099-12-31



fiddle
